# ParseServer remove Installations with "Unregistered" status

Tags: node.js, push-notification, parse-server

When I use `Parse.Push.send` I have some of my installations which return "status 410, unregistered device". How can I automatically remove them from my installation schema ?

Answer (score 0):

deleting installations requires **masterKey** access so you have 2 options:

1. Delete it manually using some database tool or I recommend to use [parse-dashboard](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-dashboard)
2. Delete in code via cloud code functions - you need to create cloud code function that will receive the installation id as parameter and will delete it using masterKey. This cloud code function can do the work for you:

```js
Parse.Cloud.define("removeInstallation", function (req, res) {

    if (!req.params.installationId) {
        res.error("installation id is required!");
        return;
    }

    var query = new Parse.Query("_Installation");
    query.equalTo("objectId", req.params.installationId);

    query.first({
        useMasterKey: true
    }).then((insallations) => {
        return Parse.Object.destroyAll(insallations, {
            useMasterKey: true
        });
    }).then(() => {
        res.success(true);
    }, function (err) {
        res.err(err);
    });

});
```

Then this cloud code function can be triggered from your code or from any REST client.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Ran ! So if you have 20k installations you have to check manualy which one is unregistered  ? Then call your cloud function for each installation one by one ?

Comment: Hi @Charlyberthet you can create a job that will do it for you instead of manually checking it. Also, you can call this cloud code function from anywhere (e.g. your client, other server or some custom web app)